# Unable to get gMarker from markersScope

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using angular google maps and I am plotting markers on my map without any problem.

However when I try to use the infowindows and show the marker window, I get the following error: "Unable to get gMarker from markersScope!"

my markers are as follows:

```
var marker = {
        id: item['id'],
        // icon: icon,
        latitude: item['data_1'],
        longitude: item['data_2'],
        title: item['title'],
        show: false,
        fit: true,
        isIconVisibleOnClick: true,
        closeClick: 'none'
    };
```

and my html is:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map id="map" center="map.center" pan="map.pan" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" refresh="map.refresh" options="map.options" events="map.events" bounds="map.bounds">
                <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" fit=true icon="'icon'" click="onClick" events="map.events"  options="'options'">
                    <ui-gmap-windows show="'show'">
                        <div ng-non-bindable>{{title}}</div>
                    </ui-gmap-windows>
                </ui-gmap-markers>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

The window actually shows up correctly with the correct information, but the error is thrown nonetheless.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Are you using any async tasks?

Comment: Maybe your error is thrown because it's checking before the window is loaded?

Comment: I don't think so because I add the markers inside the "uiGmapIsReady.promise()" function...

Comment: Try adding some print statements to see where the flow is messing up?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation at least those are required:

```
models
coords
templateParameter
isIconVisibleOnClick
closeClick
```

So You need something along those lines:

```
<ui-gmap-windows show="'show'"
  models="..."
  coords="..."
  templateParameter="..."
  isIconVisibleOnClick="..."
  closeClick="...">
    <div ng-non-bindable>{{title}}</div>
</ui-gmap-windows>
```